# Have pending intent in notification cancel alarm

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

This is the main activity where we initialize some variables.
Also has the on click listener for the on or off button.

```
package com.example.android.alarm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AlarmManager alarm_manager;
    TimePicker alarm_timepicker;
    Context context;
    ToggleButton button;
    TextView textView;
    PendingIntent pending_intent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.context = this;

        // Initialize alarm manager

        alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Initialize time picker

        alarm_timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker3);

        // Initialize calendar intent

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Initialize text view

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // create alarm receiver intent

        final Intent my_intent= new Intent(this.context, Alarm_Receiver.class);

        // Initialize buttons

        button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleB);

        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                // Setting calendar to the time picked on time picker

                int hour;
                int min;

                int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                if (currentApiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
                    hour = alarm_timepicker.getHour();
                    min = alarm_timepicker.getMinute();
                } else {
                    hour = alarm_timepicker.getCurrentHour();
                    min = alarm_timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
                }

                String min_string = Integer.toString(min);
                String hour_string = Integer.toString(hour);

                if (hour > 12) {
                    hour_string = Integer.toString(hour - 12);
                }

                if (min < 10) {
                    min_string = "0" + Integer.toString(min);
                }



                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);


                if (isChecked) {

                    // put an extra string in my_intent
                    // tells the clock that yoe set the alarm on

                    my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");


                    // create pending intent that delays intent until alarm time

                    pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
                            my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    // set alarm manager

                    alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                            pending_intent);


                    set_text("Alarm set to: " + hour_string + ":" + min_string);

                } else {

                    set_text("Alarm is off!" );

                    // Cancel the alarm

                    alarm_manager.cancel(pending_intent);

                    // put extra string into my_intent
                    // tells the clock you turned the alarm off

                    my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm off");

                    // Cancel the ringtone

                    sendBroadcast(my_intent);

                }
            }
        });
        }

    private Activity mCurrentActivity = null;
    public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
        return mCurrentActivity;
    }
    public void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrentActivity){
        this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrentActivity;
    }

    private void set_text(String output) {
        textView.setText(output);

    }

}
```

This is the Ringtone Playing Service where the notification function is located. I already added the button to the notification and it does call the intent, but I don't know how to set up the intent and pending intent in a way that it would turn off the alarm?

```
package com.example.android.alarm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.security.Provider;

public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {

    int startId;
    boolean isRunning;

    MediaPlayer media_song;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);


        String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");

        Log.e("ringtone extra is", state);



        // Converts the extra strings from intent to startIds, 0 or 1

        assert state != null;
        switch (state) {
            case "alarm on":
                startId = 1;
                Log.e("start id is", Integer.toString(startId));

                break;
            case "alarm off":
                startId = 0;
                Log.e("start id is", Integer.toString(startId));
                break;
            default:
                startId = 0;
                break;
        }

        // if else statements

        // no music + alarm on is pressed -> music should play

        if (!this.isRunning && startId == 1) {

            Log.e("no music", "want on");

            // Intent for notification banner to stop alarm
            // THIS IS WHERE IDK WHAT TO PUT 

            // creating an instance of the media player
            media_song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.stranger_things);

            // start the ringtone
            media_song.start();

            this.isRunning = true;
            this.startId = 0;

            // notification
            // Setup notification service

            NotificationManager notify_manager = (NotificationManager)
                    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // setup an intent that goes to the main activity

            Intent intent_main_activity = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            // setup pending intent

            PendingIntent pending_intent_main_activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    intent_main_activity, 0);

            // make the notification parameters

            Notification notification_popup = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("An alarm is going off!")
                    .setContentText("Click me!")
                    .setContentIntent(pending_intent_main_activity)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "BUTTON 1", stopAlarmPendingIntent) // #0
                    .add
                    .build();

            // setup notification call command

            notify_manager.notify(0, notification_popup);
        }

        // music + alarm off is pressed -> music should stop

        else if (this.isRunning && startId == 0) {

            Log.e("music", "want off");

            // stop the ringtone
            media_song.stop();
            media_song.reset();

            this.isRunning = false;
            this.startId = 0;

        }

        // no music + alarm off is pressed -> nothing

        else if (!this.isRunning) {

            Log.e("no music", "alarm off");

            this.isRunning = false;
            this.startId = 0;

        }

        // catch odd events (possible bugs)

        else {

            Log.e("How did this", "happen?");

            this.isRunning = true;
            this.startId = 1;

        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        this.isRunning = false;

        // Tell the user we stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "on Destroy called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

This is the Alarm_Receiver that takes in an intent from the Main activity and sends one to Ringtone playing service

```
package com.example.android.alarm;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Alarm_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        Log.e("We are in the receiver", "Yay!");

        // fetch extra strings from the intent

        String get_your_string = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");

        Log.e("What is the key?", get_your_string);

        // create a receiver to the ringtone service

        Intent service_intent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);

        // pass the extra string from Main activity to Ringtone Playing Service

        service_intent.putExtra("extra", get_your_string);

        // Start the ringtone service

        context.startService(service_intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code. Please indicate exactly where you are having a problem. Nobody is going to read through all of this code. You need to trim down the code and make your question more precise. What exactly is your problem? It isn't obvious from the code and text you've posted.